# if else Condition in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i want the user select duration before he/she continue click the checkbox(Cagayan) how to do that? 
this is my code

```
Private Sub Rcagayan_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cagayan.CheckedChanged
    If Duration.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Duration", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End if

    If Cagayan.Checked = False Then
        Abulug.Checked = False
        Allacapan.Checked = False
        Alcala.Checked = False
        Amulung.Checked = False
        Aparri.Checked = False
        Baggao.Checked = False
        Ballesteros.Checked = False
        Buguey.Checked = False
        Camal.Checked = False
        Claveria.Checked = False
        Enrile.Checked = False
        Gattaran.Checked = False
        Gonzaga.Checked = False
        Iguig.Checked = False
        Lasam.Checked = False
        Lallo.Checked = False
        Pamplona.Checked = False
        Penablanca.Checked = False
        Piat.Checked = False
        Rizal.Checked = False
        SantaAna.Checked = False
        StaTere.Checked = False
        Santonino.Checked = False
        Praxedes.Checked = False
        Sanchez.Checked = False
        Solana.Checked = False
        Tuao.Checked = False
        Tugue.Checked = False

        btnUncheckedckbExpectedFalse.PerformClick()
        btnAdvicedUnchecked.PerformClick()
        Me.btncagayan.PerformClick()
        Me.btnTstmFormat.PerformClick()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Add a Return inside the first If

Comment: Or change the first `End If` to `Else`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add exit sub at the end of your first if block...

```
    Private Sub Rcagayan_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cagayan.CheckedChanged
        If Duration.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Duration", "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

        exit sub
End if

If Cagayan.Checked = False Then
    Abulug.Checked = False
    Allacapan.Checked = False
    Alcala.Checked = False
    Amulung.Checked = False
    Aparri.Checked = False
    Baggao.Checked = False
    Ballesteros.Checked = False
    Buguey.Checked = False
    Camal.Checked = False
    Claveria.Checked = False
    Enrile.Checked = False
    Gattaran.Checked = False
    Gonzaga.Checked = False
    Iguig.Checked = False
    Lasam.Checked = False
    Lallo.Checked = False
    Pamplona.Checked = False
    Penablanca.Checked = False
    Piat.Checked = False
    Rizal.Checked = False
    SantaAna.Checked = False
    StaTere.Checked = False
    Santonino.Checked = False
    Praxedes.Checked = False
    Sanchez.Checked = False
    Solana.Checked = False
    Tuao.Checked = False
    Tugue.Checked = False

    btnUncheckedckbExpectedFalse.PerformClick()
    btnAdvicedUnchecked.PerformClick()
    Me.btncagayan.PerformClick()
    Me.btnTstmFormat.PerformClick()
End If

 End Sub
```